# Simulate Clicking on link to show notification - jQuery and CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can currently only show a notification bar by physically clicking on the link. I want this to be automated by jQuery simulating a click to show the notification bar.

The notification code is:

```
<div class="success message" id="success_message">
    <h3>Success!</h3>
    <p>Reserved Listing has been added to the system!</p>
</div>
```

Which only shows if I click on:

```
<a href="#" class="trigger success-trigger">Test</a>
```

Any help on a jQuery script to simulate clicking the above code would be highly appreciated. I am aware I would need an id tag to reference it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.success-trigger").click();
```

Comment: OP is looking for something that simulates a click, not an actual click.

Comment: And this is not a click simulated ?

Comment: as I read the OP this answers the question just fine.  I'd love to hear more about why motoxer4533 doesn't believe this is a legit answer.

Comment: one thought...If you use a.success-trigger then you'd have to change your javascript if you choose to change this from an anchor to say a button or something else.  Since the OP states that he knows he needs an ID, the ID will be sufficient to select the right item and not limit the javascript to working with ONLY an achor tag.

Comment: I'm agree with you ! It was just an example for his actual code :)

Comment: I guess you could be right. I'm thinking that 'simulate' means act like a click without really clicking.

Comment: @motoxer4533, simulates means not an actual user-generated click.. The only alternative is a code-generated one and the answer does just that..

Comment: I see. I was thinking that there needed to be a .click(function()... I wasn't aware you could use .click() like this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only anchor that triggers your success bar then you should use an ID.  Either way something like:

```
<a id="successTrigger"></a>

`$("#successTrigger").trigger("click");
```

should work